# file operation - shell command or api?

Tags: java, android

In android developing, if you want to create, move, delete or even modify files, you can either call certain file APIs in the program directly or use shell commands.

Is there a general guideline regarding when I should use which?

For example, you can use

```
File.delete()
```

to delete a file, you can also use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","rm","-f","/data/logger"});
```

I'm not sure if they are the same in terms of execution, but when shall I use shell commands to deal with such operations?

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your question

Comment: The latter is ***less readable***. And the `su` executable is only present on ***rooted*** devices.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use shell commands because it is prone to attacks, for example, your users could supply a file name starting with `-`, which will be interpreted by `rm` as a switch instead of a file name.

Comment: Expertly explained, thank you! Is it possible to wrap around the file name with something like " " "?

Comment: @AsianRyanReynolds Yes you can, but the one I mentioned is just one example about how a file name can be interpreted as shell command. There are many other ones like `!` and `(`. So, don't use shell.